# How to install MariaDB 10.7 on macos

Tags: database, macos, mariadb, homebrew

I need to install MariaDB version 10.7 on Macos. It doesn’t work through Brewhome because this version is disabled there; I couldn’t find any other options on the Internet. That’s why I want to ask this question here.

I need this version for a project.

Thanks in advance for your time on this issue.

Comment: try https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/mariadb@10.7  `brew install mariadb@10.7`

Comment: note that 10.7 has been unsupported for more than a year and will not receive any security updates; consider it insecure.  strongly suggest not starting a new project using it; use one of the long term support releases 10.6 or 10.11 or the newest stable release 11.3 (supported for 27, 47, and 11 more months, respectively).  if you are doing a project for an existing production 10.7 database, plan to upgrade that database as soon as possible.